# How to define command like "| (german) for greek language? --: allowhyphens, noligature, minimal space

Tags: hyphenation, greek, kerning, shorthands

For my polutonikogreek documents I want to use commands/shortcuts like the `"|` of `germanb.ldf`, which is `\declare@shorthand{german}{"|}{\textormath{\penalty\@M\discretionary{-}{}{\kern.03em}\allowhyphens}{}}`. (Some people tend to mark and se"|parate the etymo"|logical parts of a word.) Ι've de"|fined new short"|cuts `\/` and `\|`, which I've used for Greek through"|out all of my documents, but they don't do not"|hing, for what"|ever reason.

```
\pdfgentounicode=1
\input glyphtounicode
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage{savesym,cmap}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \input{ix-utf8enc.dfu}
\input{ix-utf8enc.dfu} \usepackage[main=ngerman,greek,]{babel}
\usepackage[GlyphNames]{teubner}\savesymbol{breve} \savesymbol{aa}
\usepackage{mathpazo} \restoresymbol{pplj}{breve}\restoresymbol{pplj}{aa}
\ifFamily{pplj}{porson}
\usepackage[nonegthinspace,twothirds]{thinsp}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\,}{\thinspace\allowhyphens}%doesn't really work ...
\iflanguage{greek}{\let\/\relax}{}%doesn't work, produces "ρ"s
\let\|\relax %I need something line \/, but without allowing for linebreaks
\addto\greek@shorthands{%
  \declare@shorthand{greek}{\/}{\textormath{\penalty\@M\discretionary{-}
{}{\kern.08em}
     \allowhyphens}{}} %I don't use "|, as this has special meaning in Greek/teubner, so I choose
      \declare@shorthand{greek}{\|}{\textormath{\penalty\@M\discretionary{}{}{\kern.08em}
     \nolinebreak}{}} %the same without linebreak, e.g. if it follows the first letter of a word
    }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{otherlanguage}{greek}o\us k \es k\/d\ia\/dwsi, \as ll''\,\esa\|laben\\
οὐκ ἐκ\/δί\/δωσι, ἀλλ''\,ἔ\|λαβεν
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW: On the one hand, etymologification seems like a German peculiarity (and its disregard *is* criticized, e.g. in Schirren's review of Rapp's Aristotle-translation), on the other hand: Even if it were absolutely unusual to etymologify Greek texts and separate etyms with minimal space (the kerning can be set to 0.01em as well), it helps to overcome the well-known failings of Greek hyphenation. And it *does* make a difference, whether you hyphenate ἀ-νομο- ("without law" like in anomy) or ἀν-ομο- ("an-homo", opposite of e.g. homogenous). The reader will thank you (and I hate Oxford Uni Press).

Comment: Your example doesn't run for me as I don't have the teubner.sty. Shortcut definitions like `"|` consist of two parts: At first the startmarker  the `"` is made active and then the combination is declared. You are trying to use `\/` which is a normal (already defined) one-symbol-command. So use \renewcommand\/{...} to redefine it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: That's what I did in my latest MWE -- it doesn't work either.

Comment: I don't see a `\renewcommand\/` in your example.

Comment: Not here, but there: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205417/for-greek-insert-minimal-spacing-add-point-for-hyphenation

I tried even more new- and renewcommand's, with and without stars, none of them worked.

Let's see what I can do.

Comment: Simplify your example. You obviously got lost in the languages environments. First redefine the command globally and test it. You can then later think how to do it only for some languages.