# For greek: insert minimal spacing, add point for hyphenation

Tags: hyphenation, greek, ligatures, eledmac, eledpar

I want to define for greek a command/shortcut similar to the german `|`, which inserts minimal space and marks the (by far) preferred point for hyphenation. Additionally I need a second command/shortcut like the first which does not allow for hyphenation at this point. Everything I tried failed: In the best case it does nothing, in the worst case it inserts `|` and in the very worst case eledmac and eledpar break (though ledmac and ledpar work).
As I have used `\/` and `\|` throughout the document, I'd be glad if I could define these commands in the appropriate way without replacing them.
The MWE is my latest attempt, which fails as usual. (It is somewhat longer, because I need some interaction with eledmac/eledpar)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=ngerman,greek]{babel}
\languageattribute{greek}{polutoniko}
\usepackage[GlyphNames]{teubner}
\savesymbol{breve}
\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}
\ifFamily{pplj}{porson}
\usepackage{calc}\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[nonegthinspace,twothirds]{thinsp}
\usepackage{eledmac}
\usepackage{eledpar}
\usepackage[babel,kerning=true,tracking=true]{microtype}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\SOK}{\makebox[\widthof{FAI.}][r]{\textgreek{\scshape SW.}}\makebox[\widthof{xx}][r]{}}
\newcommand{\PHAI}{\makebox[\widthof{FAI.}][r]{\textgreek{\scshape FAI.}}\makebox[\widthof{xx}][r]{}}
renewcommand{\,}{\thinspace\linebreak[1]}
%%now it comes (this is the latest attempt, which failed like all others
\addto\extrasgreek{
   \let\|\relax
   \let\/\relax
   \newcommand*{\/}{\discretionary{-}{}{\kern.08em}\linebreak[2]}
   \renewcommand*{\|}{\ifmmode\mskip1mu\else\kern.08em\linebreak[0]\fi}
    }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
  \selectlanguage{polutonikogreek}
   \beginnumbering
   \autopar
   SWKRATHS\quad\>\~W f\ia le Fa\ic dre,  po\ic{}d\hg{} ka\ig{} p\oa\/jen?

   \textsc{SWKRATHS}\quad Par\ag{} Lus\ia ou, \wsc{} S\wa krates, to\uc{}  Kef\aa lou, pore\ua omai d\eg{} 
   pr\oG s per\ia\/paton \esa xw te\ia qous; suqn\oG n g\ag r \es ke\ic{}  di\/\ea\/triya qr\oa non 
   kaj\/\ha menos \es x \er w\/jino\uc. t\wci{} d\eg{} s\wci{} ka\ig{} \es m\wci{} \er ta\ia r\wi{} 
   peij\oa menos \>Akoumen\wci{} kat\ag{} t\ag s \oR do\ug s poio\uc mai to\ug s peri\/p\aa tous; 
   fhs\ig{} g\ag r \as\|kopwt\ea rous e\isc nai t\wc n \es n to\ic s dr\oa mois.

   \SOK Kal\wc s g\aa r, \wsc{} \er ta\ic re, l\ea gei. \as t\ag r Lus\ia as \hsc n, 
    \wr s \esa\|oiken, \es n \asa stei?

   \PHAI Na\ia, par''\,\>Epi\/kr\aa tei, \es n t\hci\/de t\hci{} plhs\ia on to\uc{} 
   \>Olump\ia ou o\is k\ia\ai{} t\hci{} Moruq\ia\ai.

   \SOK T\ia s o\usc n d\hg{} \hsc n \hr{} dia\/trib\ha? \hsg{} d\hc lon \ora\|ti t\wc n 
   l\oa gwn \ur m\ac s Lus\ia as e\ir st\ia a?

   \PHAI Pe\ua s\hi, e\isa{} soi sqol\hg{} pro\/\id\oa nti \as ko\ua ein.

   \SOK T\ia{} d\ea? o\us k \asg n o\isa ei me kat\ag{} P\ia ndaron  ((ka\ig{}  \as\|sqol\ia as 
   \ur p\ea r\/teron)) pr\ac gma poi\ha sesjai t\oG{} s\hg n te ka\ig{} Lus\ia ou dia\/trib\hg n \as ko\uc sai?

   \PHAI Pr\oa\/age d\ha.

   \SOK L\ea gois \asa n.

   \PHAI Ka\ig{} m\ha n, \wsc{} S\wa\/krates, prosv\/\ha kousa g\ea{} soi \hr{} \as ko\ha; \oR{} 
   g\aa r toi l\oa gos \hsc n, per\ig{} \org n di\/e\|tr\ia bomen, o\us k o\isc d''\,\ora n\/tina 
   tr\oa pon \es rwtik\oa s. g\ea\/grafe g\ag r d\hg{} \oR{} Lus\ia as peir\wa men\oa n tina t\wc n kal\wc n, 
   o\us q \ur p''\,\es rasto\uc{} d\ea, \as ll''\,a\us t\oG{} d\hg{} to\uc to ka\ig{} ke\/k\oa myeutai; 
   l\ea gei g\ag r \wr s qarist\ea on m\hg{} \es r\wc nti m\ac llon \hsg{} \es r\wc nti.
   \pend
  \endnumbering
  \end{Leftside}
  \begin{Rightside}
  \selectlanguage{ngerman}\beginnumbering\autopar
  \emph{Sokrates} bla

  \emph{Phaidros} bla

  \emph{Sokrates} bla

  \emph{Phaidros} bla

  \emph{Sokrates} bla

  \emph{Phaidros} bla

  \emph{Sokrates} bla

  \emph{Phaidros} bla

  \emph{Sokrates} bla

  \emph{Phaidros} bla
  \pend
  \endnumbering
  \end{Rightside}
  \Pages
  \end{pages}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Greek characters (χαρακτῆρες) instead of teubner-glyphs (qarak\hc res) shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Your macros are not being used.  You have added them to the `greek` language environment definitions, but then you are starting a `polutonikogreek` environment.  They are different! Try it with `\addto\extraspolutonikogreek{...}`.

Comment: I am not sur to understand your need. But in any case you should try without eledmac to see if the problem is made by eledmac or not. (I think not, because eledmac use the default line splitting of tex).

Comment: @Maïeul: One solution worked with `ledmac` -- it didn't actually work, but it caused no harm --, but eledmac broke.

Comment: @Thruston: I though polutonikogreek activates `\extrasgreek`, but I'll try it.

Comment: @AlexanderWittmann i don't understand what you want. But if the problem is between eledmac/ledmac, you should open a issue with a MWE an a clearer explanation...

Comment: @Thruston With polutonikogreek it seems to work, but it inserts no hyphens (-) when hyphenating at the point with \/. My faut ...

Comment: <pre><code><pre><code>\addto\extraspolutonikogreek{% 
  \let\/\relax
  \DeclareRobustCommand*{\/}{\discretionary{-}{}{\kern.03em}% \linebreak[2]
  }
  \DeclareRobustCommand*{\|}{\ifmmode\mskip.3mu\else\kern.03em\nolinebreak\fi}}<\code><\pre> This works, but it looks very clumsy, like a little squirt grabbing a vuvuzela and proclaiming himself admiral of the Royal Navy.</code></pre> This works, but it looks very clumsy, like a little squirt grabbing a vuvuzela and proclaiming himself admiral of the Royal Navy.